# Launch remote builds in Jenkins with Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, jenkins, githooks, webhooks

I'm trying to launch a test suite when I push to my development branch in Heroku. 
I can do this when I deploy my application but I need to in my development branch.

Anybody know what can I do?

Comment: What part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks for your response, the problem is that test are launched when I push a stable version, but I need to launch it when I push a development version, for later Merge development to master